# Drag and drop from my app's ListView to external apps (such as Windows Explorer)

Tags: c++, listview, winapi, drag-and-drop, shell-extensions

I have a a `ListView` containing a list of files:

```
hList = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_LISTVIEW, L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT, 0, 0, 500, 400, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_LISTVIEW, hInst, NULL);
```

Let's say it contains a row `c:\temp\hello.txt`.

**How to enable drag and drop of this file from my application's `ListView` to external applications (such as Windows Explorer) as "Copy"?**

[image]

The GUI part of the question might be obvious ([or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365106/how-do-i-create-a-drag-and-drop-start-event-in-report-listview-in-winapi)) via:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
{
    ...
    case LVN_BEGINDRAG:
```

But here this question is about the actual sending of the file to external applications, such as Windows Explorer. How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drag and Drop Support for win32 GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345435/drag-and-drop-support-for-win32-gui)

Comment: No @VTT that's the contrary (from browser to my app)! Here I want the contrary: from my app to external apps.

Comment: This case is also discussed at that thread. Just looks at second answer explaining `IDropSource` and at third with links.

Comment: The so-called-duplicate question clearly states the inverse request @VTT, and the answer you mention is just 2 links (should rather be comments), thus I think maybe this actual question still is relevant, for these 2 reasons, can you reconsider, what do you think?

Comment: The answer I mentioned contains a rather verbose explanations of how drag and drop supposed to work that is totally relevant in context of this question. Maybe this question deserved it's own answer, but that is why duplicate is just *possible*.

Comment: Why not search the web? This has been asked many times. You think you are the first to ask here?

Comment: Why do you think I haven't @DavidHeffernan? It's quite hard to find a working code for this specific thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that implements all that is required to perform such a ListView file drag&drop. First some includes:

```
#define CINTERFACE
#define COBJMACROS
#include "ShObjIdl.h"
#include "ShlObj.h"
#include "oleidl.h"
```

Then this in the `WinMain` function, to initialize OLE operations.

```
OleInitialize(NULL);
InitCommonControls();
```

Then, the `IDropSource` part:

```
typedef struct __DSV_TDropSource {
    IDropSource     This;
    IDropSourceVtbl Func;
    ULONG           RefCnt;
} __DSV_TDropSource;

HRESULT WINAPI __DSV_QueryInterface(IDropSource *This, REFIID riid, void **ppvObject)
{
    IUnknown *punk = NULL;

    if (riid == IID_IUnknown)
    {
        punk = (IUnknown*)This;
    }
    else if (riid == IID_IDropSource)
    {
        punk = (IUnknown*)This;
    }

    *ppvObject = punk;

    if (punk)
    {
        IUnknown_AddRef(punk);
        return S_OK;
    }
    else {
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
}

ULONG WINAPI __DSV_AddRef(IDropSource *This)
{
    __DSV_TDropSource *pThis = (__DSV_TDropSource*)This;
    return pThis->RefCnt++;
}

ULONG WINAPI __DSV_Release(IDropSource *This)
{
    __DSV_TDropSource *pThis = (__DSV_TDropSource*)This;

    LONG iRes = (LONG)pThis->RefCnt - 1;
    if (iRes < 1) { iRes = 0; }
    pThis->RefCnt = iRes;

    if (iRes == 0) { free(pThis); }
    return iRes;
}

HRESULT WINAPI __DSV_QueryContinueDrag(IDropSource *This, BOOL fEscapePressed, DWORD grfKeyState)
{
    if (fEscapePressed) { return DRAGDROP_S_CANCEL; }

    if (!(grfKeyState & (MK_LBUTTON | MK_RBUTTON))) { return DRAGDROP_S_DROP; }

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT WINAPI __DSV_GiveFeedback(IDropSource *This, DWORD dwEffect)
{
    return DRAGDROP_S_USEDEFAULTCURSORS;
}

IDropSource* CreateDropSource()
{
    __DSV_TDropSource *pResu = (__DSV_TDropSource*)malloc(sizeof(__DSV_TDropSource));
    if (!pResu) { return 0; }

    pResu->This.lpVtbl = &(pResu->Func);
    pResu->Func.QueryInterface = __DSV_QueryInterface;
    pResu->Func.AddRef = __DSV_AddRef;
    pResu->Func.Release = __DSV_Release;
    pResu->Func.QueryContinueDrag = __DSV_QueryContinueDrag;
    pResu->Func.GiveFeedback = __DSV_GiveFeedback;

    pResu->RefCnt = 1;
    return (IDropSource*)pResu;
}


void** GetFileUiObject(TCHAR *ptFile, REFIID riid)
{

    void** pInterfaceResu = 0;
    IShellFolder *pFolder;
    PIDLIST_RELATIVE pFile;
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pITEMDLIST_File;
    HRESULT iResu;

    pITEMDLIST_File = ILCreateFromPath(ptFile);
    if (!pITEMDLIST_File)
        return 0;

    iResu = SHBindToParent(pITEMDLIST_File, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)&pFolder, (PCUITEMID_CHILD*)&pFile);
    if (iResu != S_OK)
        return 0;

    const ITEMIDLIST* pArray[1] = { pFile };
    iResu = IShellFolder_GetUIObjectOf(pFolder, NULL, 1, pArray, riid, NULL, (void**)&pInterfaceResu);
    if (iResu != S_OK)
        return 0;

    IShellFolder_Release(pFolder);

    return pInterfaceResu;
}
```

Lastly, this should be performed in the message loop:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
        pdi = (NMLVDISPINFO*) lParam;
        nmlv = (NMLISTVIEW*) lParam;
        switch (pdi->hdr.code)
        {

        case LVN_BEGINDRAG:
            wstring fName = L"C:\\test.txt";
            IDataObject *pObj;
            IDropSource *pSrc;
            pObj = (IDataObject*)GetFileUiObject(LPWSTR(fName.c_str()), IID_IDataObject);
            if (!pObj)
                break;

            pSrc = CreateDropSource();
            if (!pSrc)
            {
                IDataObject_Release(pObj);
                break;
            }

            DWORD dwEffect;
            DoDragDrop(pObj, pSrc, DROPEFFECT_COPY | DROPEFFECT_LINK, &dwEffect);

            IDropSource_Release(pSrc);
            IDataObject_Release(pObj);
            break;
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement `IDropSource`, `IDropSourceNotify` (optional) and `IDataObject` and call [`DoDragDrop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678486(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If you are developing an application that can act as a data source for an OLE drag-and-drop operation, you must call DoDragDrop when you detect that the user has started an OLE drag-and-drop operation.
>
> The DoDragDrop function enters a loop in which it calls various methods in the IDropSource and IDropTarget interfaces. (For a successful drag-and-drop operation, the application acting as the data source must also implement IDropSource, while the target application must implement IDropTarget.)

[`SHCreateDataObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762126(v=vs.85).aspx) can provide a `IDataObject` instance for you but you often end up having to [code your own](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080311-00/?p=23153) because the shell provided implementation is [not perfect](https://web.archive.org/web/20120707061222/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776390(v=vs.85).aspx#1).

[`IDragSourceHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762034(v=vs.85).aspx) can help you to get a fancy drag image.

See also:

- [Dragging a shell object, part 1: Getting the IDataObject](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041206-00/?p=37133)
- [What a drag: Dragging a virtual file (HGLOBAL edition)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080318-00/?p=23083/)
- [What a drag: Dragging a virtual file (IStream edition)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080319-00/?p=23073/)
- [What a drag: Dragging a virtual file (IStorage edition)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080320-00/?p=23063)

Comment: Thanks Anders. the link for "is not perfect" doesn't work, do you still have it? Also why is IDropSourceNotify optional? What happens if I don't use it?

Comment: The link works fine, basically you can't use CFSTR_FILECONTENTS because the data object only supports index -1. Maybe https://archive.is/xVH4X works better for you. The notify is optional because you might not care about the window type the user is dropping into.